# Issue with parsing of Rascal DSL

Tags: parsing, dsl, rascal

I am unable to parse a language instance.

The parser complains about the first line (test_exe).

```
#
# example
#
set(TARGET_NAME test_exe)

set(${TARGET_NAME}_IDE_FOLDER "path/path")

set(${TARGET_NAME}_DIRS
    ${PATH}/a/inc
    ${PATH}/b/inc
)

set(${TARGET_NAME}_SOURCES
    example.c
)

set(${TARGET_NAME}_DEPS
    ${COMMON_DEPS}
)

configureTestExecutable(${TARGET_NAME} OBJ_TEST)
```

The above is a recurring section in language instances.

If I replace the last line with

```
configureLibrary(${TARGET_NAME} OBJ_TEST)
```

it does work.

I tried

```
syntax Configure = configure: ConfigureTestExecutable;
syntax Configure = configure: ConfigureTestExecutable+;
syntax Configure = configure: ConfigureTestExecutable*;
```

all do not work.

This

```
syntax Configure = configure: ConfigureLibrary;
syntax Configure = configure: ConfigureLibrary+;
syntax Configure = configure: ConfigureLibrary*;
```

does work somehow.

```
start syntax Build = build: Section+ sections;

layout Layout = Comment*;

lexical Comment = @category="Comment" "#" ![\n]* [\n]; 

syntax Section = section: Target target Options+ options;

syntax Target = target: "set" "(" Id targetMacro Id targetName ")";

syntax Options = options: IdeFolder Dirs Sources Deps Configure; 

syntax IdeFolder = ideFolder: "set" "(" "$" "{" Id targetMacro "}" "_IDE_FOLDER" "\"" Id ideFolderPath "\"" ")";

syntax Dirs = dirs: "set" "(" "$" "{" Id targetMacro "}" "_DIRS" DirsPath+ dirPaths ")";

syntax DirsPath = dirPaths: "$" "{" Id pathMacro "}" Id? path;

syntax Sources = sources: "set" "(" "$" "{" Id targetMacro "}" "_SOURCES" SourceList+ sourceList ")"; 

syntax Configure = configure: 

//ConfigureLibrary* 

ConfigureTestExecutable;

//syntax ConfigureLibrary = configureLibrary: "configureLibrary" "(" "$" "{" Id targetMacro "}" Id buildTarget ")";

syntax ConfigureTestExecutable = configureTestExecutable: "configureTestExecutable" "(" "$" "{" Id targetMacro "}" Id buildTarget ")";
```

The parse error I get is:

```
rascal>x = parse(|project://Instrumentation/src/CMakeLists.cmake|); 
|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(15449,5,<447,107>,<447,112>): ParseError(|project://Instrumentation/src/CMakeLists.cmake|(32,1,<4,15>,<4,16>))
        at parse(|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(15449,5,<447,107>,<447,112>))
        at $root$(|prompt:///|(4,56,<1,4>,<1,60>))
        at *** somewhere ***(|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(15449,5,<447,107>,<447,112>))
        at parse(|std:///ParseTree.rsc|(15449,5,<447,107>,<447,112>))
        at $root$(|prompt:///|(4,56,<1,4>,<1,60>))
```

Answer (score 2):

I changed

```
layout Layout = Comment*;

lexical Comment = @category="Comment" "#" ![\n]* [\n];
```

to

```
layout Layout = WhitespaceAndComment* !>> [\ \t\n\r#];

lexical WhitespaceAndComment = [\ \t\n\r] | @category="Comment" "#" ![\n]* $;
```

after reading the Pico syntax [1](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Recipes/Languages/Pico/Syntax/Syntax.html) example and now it works. Thanks @Davy to put me on the right track (observation 1).

Answer (score 0):

Two observations:

1. The layout definition does not include whitespace, but since part of the grammar is missing, I can't figure out if this is intentional (like layout sensitive parsing) or part of the problem.
2. Did you parse with `#Build` or `#start[Build]`? You need the second one to handle layout at beginning or end of the file.

So maybe you have to extend the question a bit?

Also, check if your parse tree is correct after it succeeded, because it might be parsing everything as a big string?